# Scrapy imports really slow

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy but the setup time is really slow.

```
start_time = time.time()
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from scrapy.utils.sitemap import Sitemap, sitemap_urls_from_robots
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
print('Completed imports. Total time: ' + str(time.time() - start_time))
# Completed imports. Total time: 5.819392919540405
```

Why is this so slow? Has Scrapy cached data somewhere that it's loading each time it starts up?

Comment: Scrapy is a big library, data wouldn't be cached anywhere, that's not how it works. It just takes a while to load.

Comment: So is the workaround to only call Scrapy when absolutely necessary?